# Heroku: Push rejected and failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, heroku

It's my first questions here --> You can assume my frustration level :-D

I am trying to push my Rails app to Heroku. It works entirely fine on my local machine. For he deployment on Heroku, I simply connected it to Github.

When i push the code to Heroku, I receive the following error message:

`!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.`

`!     Push failed`

**Does anyone have an idea what I should do?**

I tried `bundle install` or deleting the gemfile.lock, but nothing worked

Would appreciate it a lot!
Best
Dan

Full error message below:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching rake 13.0.6
       Installing rake 13.0.6
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Fetching minitest 5.14.4
       Fetching zeitwerk 2.4.2
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing zeitwerk 2.4.2
       Installing minitest 5.14.4
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.4
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
       Installing builder 3.2.4
       Fetching erubi 1.10.0
       Installing erubi 1.10.0
       Fetching racc 1.5.2
       Fetching crass 1.0.6
       Fetching rack 2.2.3
       Installing crass 1.0.6
       Installing rack 2.2.3
       Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
       Fetching nio4r 2.5.7
       Installing nio4r 2.5.7 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Fetching marcel 1.0.1
       Installing marcel 1.0.1
       Fetching mini_mime 1.1.0
       Fetching msgpack 1.4.2
       Installing msgpack 1.4.2 with native extensions
       Installing mini_mime 1.1.0
       Using bundler 2.2.21
       Fetching i18n_data 0.11.0
       Installing i18n_data 0.11.0
       Fetching sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.2.0
       Installing sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.2.0
       Fetching unicode_utils 1.4.0
       Installing unicode_utils 1.4.0
       Fetching ffi 1.15.3
       Installing ffi 1.15.3 with native extensions
       Fetching thor 1.1.0
       Installing thor 1.1.0
       Fetching method_source 1.0.0
       Installing method_source 1.0.0
       Fetching pg 1.2.3
       Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
       Fetching ruby_http_client 3.5.2
       Installing ruby_http_client 3.5.2
       Fetching tilt 2.0.10
       Installing tilt 2.0.10
       Fetching stripe 5.37.0
       Installing stripe 5.37.0
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
       Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
       Installing rack-test 1.1.0
       Fetching rack-proxy 0.7.0
       Installing rack-proxy 0.7.0
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
       Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
       Fetching i18n 1.8.10
       Installing i18n 1.8.10
       Fetching sprockets 4.0.2
       Installing sprockets 4.0.2
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching countries 3.1.0
       Installing countries 3.1.0
       Fetching sort_alphabetical 1.1.0
       Installing sort_alphabetical 1.1.0
       Fetching puma 4.3.8
       Installing puma 4.3.8 with native extensions
       Fetching figaro 1.2.0
       Installing figaro 1.2.0
       Fetching nokogiri 1.11.7 (x86_64-linux)
       Installing nokogiri 1.11.7 (x86_64-linux)
       Fetching sendgrid-ruby 6.4.0
       Installing sendgrid-ruby 6.4.0
       Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
       Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
       Fetching bootsnap 1.7.5
       Installing bootsnap 1.7.5 with native extensions
       Fetching activesupport 6.0.4
       Installing activesupport 6.0.4
       Fetching country_select 4.0.0
       Installing country_select 4.0.0
       Fetching sassc 2.4.0
       Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
       Fetching loofah 2.10.0
       Installing loofah 2.10.0
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.2
       Installing globalid 0.4.2
       Fetching activemodel 6.0.4
       Installing activemodel 6.0.4
       Fetching jbuilder 2.11.2
       Installing jbuilder 2.11.2
       Fetching stripe_event 2.3.1
       Installing stripe_event 2.3.1
       Fetching wicked_pdf 2.1.0
       Installing wicked_pdf 2.1.0
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Fetching activejob 6.0.4
       Installing activejob 6.0.4
       Fetching activerecord 6.0.4
       Installing activerecord 6.0.4
       Fetching actionview 6.0.4
       Installing actionview 6.0.4
       Fetching actionpack 6.0.4
       Installing actionpack 6.0.4
       Fetching actioncable 6.0.4
       Installing actioncable 6.0.4
       Fetching activestorage 6.0.4
       Installing activestorage 6.0.4
       Fetching actionmailer 6.0.4
       Installing actionmailer 6.0.4
       Fetching railties 6.0.4
       Installing railties 6.0.4
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Fetching simple_form 5.1.0
       Installing simple_form 5.1.0
       Fetching actionmailbox 6.0.4
       Installing actionmailbox 6.0.4
       Fetching actiontext 6.0.4
       Installing actiontext 6.0.4
       Fetching webpacker 4.3.0
       Installing webpacker 4.3.0
       Fetching rails 6.0.4
       Installing rails 6.0.4
       Fetching lockup 1.6.1
       Installing lockup 1.6.1
       Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
       Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
       Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
       Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 70 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Bundle completed (269.10s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     NameError: uninitialized constant Dotenv
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
 !     /tmp/build_fa9b47c5/bin/rake:9:in `<main>'
 !
/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Dotenv
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:710:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/tmp/build_fa9b47c5/bin/rake:9:in `<main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1007:in `rake'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:72:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1028:in `allow_git'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:105:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:91:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:35:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:34:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:20:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails6.rb:18:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: What is the **FULL (!!!)** error message? The issue is *most likely* that you haven't correctly committed the up-to-date `Gemfile.lock`, for example, perhaps you didn't run `git push`, or perhaps you're not working on the `main`/`master` branch.

Comment: The answer is definitely *not* to delete the `Gemfile.lock`. That's the exact opposite of the solution.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose w/o the error log, but a general tip: you say your app works fine locally, but is that running `ENV=production`? Heroku runs your production environment (by default). Ensuring that your app runs the production environment locally first is way easier than diagnosing basic config issues pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace

Comment: @TomLord thank you for your comment. I have added the full error message.

Comment: @DanHH The error message says: `uninitialized constant Dotenv`, from line 9 of `config/application.rb`. My guess is that you need to take another look at [the dotenv REAME](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#rails) and follow the instructions carefully; you've probably copied the first two code snippets without reading the third paragraph. In short: You probably don't actually need to mention `Dotenv` in `config/application.rb`, but if you do, then you must add  `gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'` to the `Gemfile`, **not** `gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]`.

Comment: However I cannot confidently say that's the answer at the moment, because I haven't actually seen any of your code. What's in `config/application.rb`, and what's in the `Gemfile`? The important lesson here is to read the full error message, not just the last line of the error message. Very often in programming, *you need to scroll up* to find the critical information in an error.